# getting file path through console c#

Tags: c#

i have a program where i want to get filepath from console, for example program asks me to type a path of file, but here is the problem i dont want to write the whole path down. I would like to eather use openfiledialog or create a text file within the solution and get path from there. Here is a short code from the section:

```
string input;
Console.WriteLine("Type path file: ");
input = Console.ReadLine();

string readText = File.ReadAllText(input);

Tree HuffmanTree = new Tree();

// Build the Huffman tree
HuffmanTree.Build(readText);
```

And i already created a Text.txt file within aplication, and i am making console aplication in c#. The error is that the program cant find a path name eg. Text.txt but if i use whole path instead of "input" program works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure your .txt file is in the same directory as the .exe you are running

You can make VisualStudio to copy it to your debug location with:

Click on your file in your solution explorer and set the "Copy to Output Directory" option

[image: Solution Explorer]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your paths and things have @ before the string, like @"c:\" to escape any character literals. Also know that if the text file is next to the EXE you do not need to provide the full path, you only provide the filename, in this instance it would be "test.txt"

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;    

public static string getPathFromUser(string path)
    {
        if (File.Exists("test.txt"))
        {
            string k = Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllLines("test.txt").Single(d => d.ToLower().Contains(path.ToLower())), @"\w+:", "\0");
            return k != null || k != string.Empty ? k : "Unknown option.";
        }
        else
        {
            File.AppendAllText("test.txt", "home:");
            return "No file found, made one instead";
        }
    }
```

The txt would look something like this:

[image]